# Reliably parse unpredictable CSV formats

Tags: ruby, csv

I'm looking for some kind of solution to a problem we're having importing CSV files with Ruby. We keep running into all kinds of exceptions ranging from malformed lines to line ending problems. Right now we're using FasterCSV and have this hacky exception catching solution to try different combinations of delimiters and quotation styles. I don't like it.

All in all, it's an inelegant solution and it seems like this shouldn't be something we should have to deal with. I'm looking for a lib, in any language, that I can point to a file and it'll just figure out how it's formatted and give me the data I need from any CSV.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Python CSV package](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html) is pretty good at this. However, when dealing with unpredictable CSV formats, I expect you'll have to do maintenance no matter what library you pick.

Comment: +1 Agreed. CSV is a non-specification. There are so many apps out there that were written before there was a spec, or where the developer thought they had the format covered correctly, and that fail miserably, that I ended up writing a separate app just to diagnose the problems with a new data feed rather than have to dig in with an editor, or worse, a hex-editor. It was always especially fun to get a text field with embedded carriage returns. I love writing code to unroll that sort of mess.